# How to solve Mongoose Error on Validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am building an API that allows the user to log certain data into the database(MongoDB) The problem is I keep getting the following errors:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: item validation failed: productName: Path `productName` is required.
```

here is my schema :

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({

   productName : {
       type : String,
       required:true
   } ,
   description : {
       type :String,
       default:true
   },
   supplier : {
       type :String,
       default:true
   },
   price : {
       type :Number,
       default:true
   },
   date : {
       type :Date,
       default:Date.now
   }
});

module.exports=Inventory=mongoose.model('item',ItemSchema,'inventory');
```

Here is the submit post route:

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Items model
const Inventory = require('../../../models/Inventory');


router.post('/',(req,res)=>{

    const newInventory= new Inventory({
        productName:req.body.productName,
        description:req.body.description,
        supplier:req.body.supplier,
        price:req.body.price,
    });
       newInventory.save().then(item=>res.json(item))
   });
```

I can't figure out why it's throwing a validation Error!

Comment: your ``req.body.productName`` is empty

Comment: check what you are getting in req.body

Comment: @sultan aslam I'm getting an empty object {}, does this means that the error is coming because I'm not getting any request(I 'm testing with postman). will this mean that my code is alright and the problem is from Postman?

Comment: yes. you set productName required and when productName is null/empty mongoose validation failed and it throw error

Answer (score 1):

This was the step I took to resolve the problem

first, i checked what i was getting from my req.body

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Items model
const Inventory = require('../../../models/Inventory');
console.log(req.body) //checking for content of req.body

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{

    const newInventory= new Inventory({
        productName:req.body.productName,
        description:req.body.description,
        supplier:req.body.supplier,
        price:req.body.price,
    });
       newInventory.save().then(item=>res.json(item))
   });
```

I got an empty object { }, this means I wasn't getting any request in the first place. Testing with Postman, I changed the option from "form data" to :

```
 x-www-form-urlencoded
```

this filled my req.body with data and the error disappeared !